# Can I ask Virtual Network related post on Network Engineering site?

Tags: discussion, support

I created an post [The Virtual Network](https://superuser.com/questions/1361420/the-vps-in-my-windows-server-2008-can-not-access-the-internet) in the Super User Site.

It's content mainly is the Virtual Machine can not connect to the Internet.

Because this is Virtual Network related, so I want to know whether this question I can ask on the Networking Engineering site.